# WPF application issue on Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2015

All,

I have a WPF / MVVM app that ran just fine on Windows 7, but now that I have upgraded my desktop to Win10 the app no longer runs. I can compile and run within the Visual Studio 15 Community environment, but when I deploy the app to a Windows 10 machine I get the thinking icon for about a second and then :::poof::: nothing.

The Event Viewer spews out the following:

Fault bucket 129057744541, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: MyApp.exe
P2: 1.0.1.0
P3: 56fac0fb
P4: MyDataModel
P5: 1.0.1.0
P6: 56f97604
P7: 5
P8: 596
P9: System.AccessViolationException
P10:

Also I get the following icon pop up briefly in my tray, [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd8aT.png)

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Make sure all of your references are set to CopyLocal=true and that they exist on the windows 10 box

Comment: I think that it could be related to some permissions, does your app read/write some files or other resources?

Comment: try to run as administrator

Comment: Run as Admin doesn't work, or the Copy Local thing. I have a signed xml file that I am reading (for software licensing purposes), and I am also reading some values from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy was I barking up the wrong tree! Turns out it was my obfuscator settings. I've reset all the settings back to default, and when deployed the app runs just fine.